# MATLAB: real-time vs. filter(b,a,z) implementation of IIR filters

Tags: matlab, filter

I am trying to understand why the real-time hard-coded IIR does not work whereas the non-real-time IIR filter function (filter()) already provided in MATLAB works. The filter that I'm testing is the following:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhDYR.png

I went through the difference equation and got this as the filter coefficients:

```
b = [0,2*10^-7];
a = [1,-1.98,1];
```

First, I set up a testing signal with various frequencies:

```
f_s = 44100;
t = 0:1/f_s:0.5;
y = sin(0.5*t) + sin(1500*t) + sin(100*t) + sin(5*t);
```

then I filtered this signal through 2 differently realized IIR filters: 1) hard-coded IIR filter that filters the signal entry by entry. 2) built-in function filter(B,A,signal) by MATLAB.

```
% hard-coded IIR
state1 = 0;
state2 = 0;
inputState = 0;
for n = 1:22051
    input = b(2) * y(1,n)
    y_buffer = inputState + a(2) * state1 + a(3) * state2;
    inputState = input;
    state2 = state1;
    state1 = y_buffer;
    y_out(1,n) = y_buffer;
end

% given MATLAB function filter(b,a,y)
y_out2 = filter(b,a,y);
```

However, when I plot the two results, the one I coded blows up to infinity, whereas the signal filtered through the MATLAB function seems to be fine.

Why are the two results different? Did I make any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply forgot about the minus sign for `a` coefficients. In your loop, `y_buffer` ought to be:

```
y_buffer = inputState - a(2) * state1 - a(3) * state2;
```